# Upload files to amazon bucket from android app using filepicker-android library

Tags: android, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I'm working on an android application in which I would like to be able to implement the Store functionality in my S3 bucket as described on their webpage https://www.inkfilepicker.com/. I have downloaded the filepicker-android library and done some rather fruitless searching and I am beginning to wonder if this has been implemented yet on the android side of things. If such functionality does exist, where should I start (what classes are relevant, are there examples)? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by" I am beginning to wonder if this has been implemented yet on the android side of thing"? They have documentation you should be reading. Otherwise if you have a specific question please clarify.

Comment: I agree with @user2045570. Here's an example using Amazon's SDK: `https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/samples/S3_Uploader/src/com/amazonaws/demo/s3uploader/S3UploaderActivity.java`. Their docs are located here: `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/`